# Invoke Lambda docker container locally by passing API Gateway like event object

Tags: docker, kubernetes, lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I am trying out the [newly added container image support](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/) for AWS Lambda service.

I have built a custom image using python-alpine as the base image. I have used the same Dockerfile mentioned in the article above. I am also able to invoke it using below command :

```
curl -v -X POST http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{}'
```

This part `-d '{}'` is actually what is passed as the event. When this function is behind an actual AWS API gateway it gets the below event

```
{"resource":"/","path":"/view","httpMethod":"POST","headers":{"Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","Accept-Language":"en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,zh-CN;q=0.4","cache-control":"max-age=0","CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto":"https","CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer":"true","CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer":"false","CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer":"false","CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer":"false","CloudFront-Viewer-Country":"GB","content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Host":"j3ap25j034.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com","origin":"https://j3ap25j034.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com","Referer":"https://j3ap25j034.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/","upgrade-insecure-requests":"1","User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36","Via":"2.0 a3650115c5e21e2b5d133ce84464bea3.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)","X-Amz-Cf-Id":"0nDeiXnReyHYCkv8cc150MWCFCLFPbJoTs1mexDuKe2WJwK5ANgv2A==","X-Amzn-Trace-Id":"Root=1-597079de-75fec8453f6fd4812414a4cd","X-Forwarded-For":"50.129.117.14, 50.112.234.94","X-Forwarded-Port":"443","X-Forwarded-Proto":"https"},"queryStringParameters":null,"pathParameters":null,"stageVariables":null,"requestContext":{"path":"/dev/","accountId":"125002137610","resourceId":"qdolsr1yhk","stage":"dev","requestId":"0f2431a2-6d2f-11e7-b799-5152aa497861","identity":{"cognitoIdentityPoolId":null,"accountId":null,"cognitoIdentityId":null,"caller":null,"apiKey":"","sourceIp":"50.129.117.14","accessKey":null,"cognitoAuthenticationType":null,"cognitoAuthenticationProvider":null,"userArn":null,"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36","user":null},"resourcePath":"/","httpMethod":"POST","apiId":"j3azlsj0c4"},"body":{"msg":"update"},"isBase64Encoded":false}
```

My codebase depends on parameters like `path`, `resource`, `isBase64Encoded`, `body`, etc. What I am trying to achieve is, make the application portable (which can run on kubernetes). Is there a tool or a way that acts as an API gateway and passes an event like the one mentioned above while invoking this function ?

I have searched for tyk, traefik but none of them can generate an event like AWS API gateway and pass it to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to simulate the API gateway events, it's actually about the payload in json format which sent to lambda function.

eg.

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name docker-aws-cdk --region ap-southeast-1 --payload '{"action":"start", "target":"dev"}' outfile
```